# Estou com um problema no meu repositório no Github - Diretórios vazios

Tags: git, github

Estou com um problema depois de enviar meu projeto no Github, que contem dois diretórios. No entanto após enviar e fazer o commit, o repositório no Github fica com as pastas vazias e com uma setinha. O que pode ter acontecido. Detalhe: já removi a pasta .git da raiz e fiz tudo de novo, mas continua dessa forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verifique se dentro da sua pasta (`backend` e `frontend`) têm um diretório .git.

Caso você tenha, é considerado um Git aninhado, pois o SHA1 é registrado com um `gitlink`.

O que você vê no GitHub é o gitlink. Isso é usado para submodulo também.

Para resolver então:

- remova o .git dentro do diretório `backend`
- remova o .git dentro do diretório `frontend`
- o .git do diretório principal (seu root) não deve ser removido

Comment: Era isso mesmo amigo. Obrigado